# Using IF formula twice with vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to use IF formula twice with Vlookup in order to extract specific data from another sheet with 2 logic commands and using this formula:

```
 =IF($Q$4=DATA!A3,master!A11=DATA!$C$2,VLOOKUP(master!O13,DATA!B3:G52,6))
```

Kindly suggest me how to apply this formula correctly.Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data?

Comment: I have to apply IF formula first to match the name of person second to match the class of bonds and than have to apply vlookup through person account number One person have invested in 5 types of bonds with same bank account and I have to bifurcate and extract according to type of bonds  and with name and if type on bond and name match then use vlookup because there are other persons also.I hope now it makes little bit sense to you.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need `AND()`:

```
=IF(AND($Q$4=DATA!A3,master!A11=DATA!$C$2),VLOOKUP(master!O13,DATA!B3:G52,6),"This
 message will appear if conditions are not met")
```

Comment: When I apply this formula it appears This
 message will appear if conditions are not met

Comment: That is because your either first or second condition is not met.

Comment: I have corrected the condition now it takes last value from extraction table each time

Comment: Can you please add example data and desired output?